# How to configure Spring Cloud Config Server to use cloned configuration files

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-config-server

My application.properties files of my Cloud Config Server looks like this.

```
config.source=Local Cloud Server #just to check where config come from
server.port=8012
encrypt.key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
spring.profiles.active=staging
spring.application.name=my-config-server
# Git Backend
spring.cloud.config.server.git.username=MY_USERNAME
spring.cloud.config.server.git.password=ghp_MY-DEV-ACCESS-TOKEN
spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=https://github.com/my-username/app-config
spring.cloud.config.server.git.clone-on-start=true
spring.cloud.config.server.git.basedir=file://${user.dir}/cloned_configurations
```

On startup a new folder "cloned_configuration" is created inside of Cloud Config Server folder. I see all of my propertie files cloned form github with correct values.

But for some reason none of these are used. For e.g config.source must have the value "GitHub" because the cloned application.repository has an entry

`config.source=GitHub`

But on application start I see "Local Cloud Server". All other settings are also not used from cloned properties.

With Postman I can receive all Configs without any issues. But none of theme are used by my Config Server or any of my other webservices.All webservices and the config server using their own application.properties file.

What I do wrong?

Comment: `All webservices and the config server using their own application.properties file`. 

Are these value from `application-staging.properties` ?

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to move your config server properties into your bootstrap.properties file instead of application.properties.

```
spring.cloud.config.server.git.username=MY_USERNAME
spring.cloud.config.server.git.password=ghp_MY-DEV-ACCESS-TOKEN
spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=https://github.com/my-username/app-config
spring.cloud.config.server.git.clone-on-start=true
spring.cloud.config.server.git.basedir=file://${user.dir}/cloned_configurations
```

https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/multi/multi__spring_cloud_config_client.html

Comment: as I know bootstra.properties file is legacy and not needed anymore.

Comment: @Tristate - I don't think it's deprecated based on the documentation: "When this HTTP server runs, it picks up the external configuration from the default local config server (if it is running) on port 8888. To modify the startup behavior, you can change the location of the config server by using bootstrap.properties (similar to application.properties but for the bootstrap phase of an application context), as shown in the following example:"

https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/reference/html/#_client_side_usage